# Add JSON(or object) to a STRING json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I have a string that looks like a JSON array with objects:

```
myJsonArray = "[
                {\"name\":\"alex\",\"weight\":\"88\"},
                {\"name\":\"Emma\",\"weight\":\"71\"}
               ]";
```

What is the easiest way to add a new object to the string?

**The string (myJsonArray) is saved to a file between the program session so I have to work on the string (myJsonArray).**

I know that Gson have a nice way to convert the string array into Java objects:

```
 MyClass[] person = gson.fromJson(myJsonArray,MyClass[].class);
```

Maybe Gson have a nice way? or not...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a POJO model of every Json-object in your **myJsonArray** and then handle it in a List, Array or what ever you need ...

**EXAMPLE**:

```
public class Person{

    @SerializedName("name")

    private String name;
    @SerializedName("weight")

    private int weight;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the weight
     */
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    /**
     * @param weight
     *            the weight to set
     */
    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", weight=" + weight + "]";
    }

    /**
     * @return json
     */
    public String toJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

}
```

**DESERIALIZE**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Person> personList = gson.fromJson(myJsonArray,Person.class);
personList.add(new Person());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer showing you how to use `GSON` to convert from `JSON` to `POJO` and vice versa. While that is the preferred approach from my point of view but, you can also make use of `GSON` only to add elements to json array.

Assuming that you have your json array string as follow:

```
String myJsonArray = "["  
            + "{\"name\":\"alex\",\"weight\":\"88\"},"  
            + "{\"name\":\"Emma\",\"weight\":\"71\"}"
            + "]";
```

Initialize `Gson` object as shown below:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
```

Convert your json String array to `JsonElement` as shown below:

```
JsonElement elements = gson.fromJson(myJsonArray, JsonElement.class);
```

Once you have `JsonElement` it contains your json array then you can convert it to `JsonArray` as shown below:

```
JsonArray arr = elements.getAsJsonArray();
```

Now you have your array as `JsonArray` and you can print them out by iterating through the elements as shown below:

```
for(JsonElement e: arr) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

And that would give you (based on above string):

```
{"name":"alex","weight":"88"}
{"name":"Emma","weight":"71"}
```

Let's assume that you want to add a new object to the existing array but, you have the object in the form of json string as follow:

```
String newObject = "{\"name\":\"Raf\", \"weight\":\"173\"}"; 

//Creates new JsonElement from json string
JsonElement newElement = gson.fromJson(newObject, JsonElement.class);
```

Now you can add this element to your existing array as follow:

```
arr.add(newElement);
```

Finally you can print your new json array as we did it before:

```
for(JsonElement e: arr) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

And the output you get is

```
{"name":"alex","weight":"88"}
{"name":"Emma","weight":"71"}
{"name":"Raf","weight":"173"}
```

Comment: This works good but is it the easiest way to add a new object to the string?

Comment: It is for you to decide which approach is the easiest depending on your requirements/scope/etc of whatever you are working on. This answer uses only **Gson**